# getting sign in alert while login failed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome

I have created a login page in angular and authenticated it to the database through API. But when I enter the wrong username or password in chrome browser I get sign in alert with my API source that

```
http://staging.xyz.com
your connection to the site is not private
```

with username and password.

But in my code, I didn't put any alert message.

I have searched for this but nothing found.

Please let me know how to block this. Any suggestions about how to do this will b helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a **security feature in browsers** to alert users when they use confidential data over **Non-SSL Connections**. To avoid such issues you need to secure your **end-points / sites** with valid **SSL certificates**.

---

#### If you already enabled the SSL,

- Check your certificate is up-to date.
- Check your certificate is valid.

---

[How to Fix “Your Connection is Not Private” Error](https://www.pandasecurity.com/mediacenter/panda-security/your-connection-is-not-private/#:%7E:text=The%20%E2%80%9Cyour%20connection%20is%20not%20private%E2%80%9D%20error%20message%20is%20exactly,the%20connection%20is%20not%20secure.&text=When%20your%20connection%20is%20not,error%20in%20the%20SSL%20certificate.)